# What is difference of protocols offered by GitHub while local git setup?

Tags: git, github, ssh, https

I am trying to setup git locally for windows using **git bash**. I am not able to differentiate pros and cons of using HTTPS and SSH protocols offered by **GitHub** while setting up local git.

While going through online resources I only understood following scenarios -

1. If we are using **SSH protocol** while cloning then to communicate to remote git repository placed over GitHub or Bitbucket or other service providers we need to setup local git SSH configuration with Public/Private key and update remote repository with that public SSH key.

   So in these case we only need to authenticate user via **ParsePhrase** we entered while setup.

   [image]
2. In case of **HTTPS protocol** while cloning we will use username/password combination to authenticate user while communication.

   [image]

Is there any other things that will differentiate these protocols in detail?

Comment: With SSH, you are less vulnerable to [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) as SSH stores and verifies the fingerprint of GitHub’s server.

Comment: Using `HTTPS` you can work behind firewall and disadvantages for each push or pull you will have to give username, password.

Comment: @VishnuAtrai note that only _outgoing_ firewalls are an issue when working with SSH, and outgoing blocks on port 22 are quite rare (and would cause much more trouble).

Comment: @RobinKrahl You're blowing past the point where the HTTPS alternative verifies a certificate each time, while the SSH variant trusts on first use and then stores the fingerprint. Both have their pro's and con's when it comes to likelihood of man-in-the-middle.

Comment: @Joost so If I concern about client server setup SSH protocol is better and for individual user git setup HTTPS right?

Answer (score 0):

There really is not that much of a difference from a usability point of view. It might depend on other factors that are specific for your configuration, such as how you manage passwords or SSH keys in your environment.

If you're using SSH anyway, it might be more convenient. If you're more of a username/password-kind-of-guy, HTTPS might be a better fit. In any case, I recommend reading the GitHub help article on the subject: https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/.